# Generating a unique coupon after completion of flash Facebook game

Tags: facebook, post, unique, coupon

Ok, so I will preface this by saying that I am very new to PHP/MySQL. I tried searching for an appropriate answer, but beyond finding an answer that hits the nail on the head I don't even know what I should search for. Thanks for help in advance.

What I am trying to do is develop a facebook app tab that houses a Flash game that I built. The caveat is that once a user 'wins' the game, I want to present them with a link inside the flash game that takes them to an html page where their coupon is presented.

I figure this means I will need three stages:
1. Authentication of User
2. The Game
3. Coupon with random URL OR content based on user input (generates a template jpeg with the persons name inserted) based on _POST data from authentication

Since this is on facebook I may try to set up the app to prompt the user to allow my app to access their info, and user their facebook user ID to generate their coupon. Alternatively, I thought I could have them input their name, and then use a cookie to carry that info over to when the coupon is created.

The main issue I am facing is how do I create the unique coupon so they can't share it with anyone else?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand things correctly, the last part is actually the simplest. You just need some kind of unique code that is specific to a single user, correct? It could actually just be a random code as long as it is stored in the db along with the user's id so that you can check whether the proper user is redeeming it. Another way is to use an encryption based on the user's id (or name if you prefer), something like:

`$code = md5($userid . 'somethingsecret');`

Of course properly authenticating the user is necessary first, but if it's a Facebook app that's pretty simple if they give the app permission.

The biggest issue may be one you haven't thought of -- ensuring that the user actually plays and wins the game. That can get very complicated depending on the level of security you need. Just remember that the url the flash redirects to when the game ends, can be manually visited as well.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to say thanks for the feedback. I haven't had a chance to look at this yet. So goes the workflow! Once this is back in front of me at work I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks again!